# get substring between character and whitespace

Tags: python, string, list, whitespace

I am trying to get a specific substring from a text file that is always located between the word "in" and and open parenthesis. ex. in TEXT (blah). I am trying to get at TEXT.

currently i am using this

```
m = text[text.find("in")+1:text.find("(")]
```

This isn't working because other sections of the larger string sometimes contain the letters i and n. So I am thinking I should change it so it is specifically looking for instances of "in" followed by whitespace.

I cannot figure hot to incorporate \s to accomplish this. How would I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Use a regular expression for this:

```
import re
preg = re.compile(r'(?<=in\s)(.*?)(?=\s\()')
for match in preg.finditer(text):
    print(match.group(0))
```

I am using positive [*lookbehinds* and *lookaheads*](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) to check for `"in "` and `" ("`.
Take a look [here](https://regex101.com/r/vT1uJ9/1), it might help understanding the regular expression better.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if text.find("in ") != -1:
    m = text[text.find("in ")+3:text.find("(")]
```